# How to solve for $x$:

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How to solve for $x$:

$5=5\sin ^2(\frac{x-4}{x^2-3x+4})+3\sin ^2(2x)$

I am unable to figure out on how to solve it.

Can someone please give some hints?

Comment: It seems very artificial.  Where did it come from?  I would just put it into Wolfram Alpha, or use the double angle formulas to replace the $\sin^2()$ with $\cos 2()$, then use the function sum formula.  No guarantees.  What did you try?

Comment: @RossMillikan; I did the same but it is going nowhere. My calculations have gone to 5 pages

Comment: With the help of Maple two solutions can be found $$.2790140986, -.6449760665$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ross Millikan commented, the problem looks so artificial that it is probably a  problem to be solved using numerical methods.

In a first step, just to have an idea,  graphing the function, I "saw" roots close to $x=-0.75$, $x=-0.65$, $x=0.25$, $x=1.50$, $x=1.85$ and $x=2.5$. These give an approximate idea of the six solutions $x_i$.

From this, if you want to polish the roots, use Newton method starting iterations with these values.

For the first root, the iterates would be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & -0.750000 \\
 1 & -0.816656 \\
 2 & -0.793850 \\
 3 & -0.790365 \\
 4 & -0.790280
\end{array}
\right)$$ and this has to be repeated for each of the roots.